# Does a "periodic" function with decreasing amplitude and wavelength have a limit?

Tags: limits

For example, for the following, is the limit as x approaches infinity 0 or does it not exist?

[image]

Bonus: Does the following limit exist as x approaches $x$? (Yeah, it was a crappy choice of variable, my bad.)

[image]

Comment: Note that your function isn't literally periodic. Having regularly-spaced zeros is one thing, but there is certainly no period $P$ such that for all $x,\ f(x + P) = f(x)$.

Comment: If it has decreasing wavelength, it isn't periodic.  Unless there is some maximum wavelength at the start and all subsequent appearant wavelengths are just divisions of that first "true" wavelength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a limit if and only if the amplitude converges towards zero